# Proving an equality in degree function in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, and a permutation $\pi$ of the vertices, denote by $\Delta_\pi$ the $\max_{1\leq i\leq n-1} \{\deg_{\{v_{i+1},...,v_n\}}(v_i)\}$. That is, we look only on the edges of $v_i$ that reach a vertex in $\{ v_{i+1},...,v_n\}$ Now for all the permutations, we define: $\mathbb{A}(G) = \min_{\pi} \{ \Delta_\pi \}$.

Another thing is that for a given sub-set of vertices $U\subseteq V$, I'll denote by $\gamma (U)$ the $\min_{u\in U} \{ \deg_{G^{'}=(U,E\uparrow_U)} (u) \}$. Meaning, the degree of $u$ in the sub-graph $G^{'}=(U,E\uparrow_U)$. Now I'll define: $\mathbb{B}(G)=\max_,_{U\subseteq V} {\gamma(U)}$.

I'd like to show that $\mathbb{B} (G) \leq \mathbb{A} (G)$. Honestly, I'm lacking any intuition as to why this even holds?

Comment: Where do you use $\pi$ in $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: @dtldarek $\mathbb{A}(G)$ is the $\max$ for all the $\pi$'s.

Comment: But there's no $\pi$ in the formula, did you mean $v_{\pi(i)}$ or $\deg_{\{v_{\pi(i+1),\ldots}\}}(v_{\pi(i)})$ or yet something else?

Comment: $\pi$ is a permutation of $V$, in the formula: $\mathbb{A}= \max_\pi \{ \Delta_\pi \}$.

Comment: Ok, so then $\mathbb{A}(G) = \max_{v \in V}\deg_G(v)$, because you can make that vertex which realizes the maximum first in $\pi$. Hence, as $\mathbb{B}(G)$ can be at most the maximum degree in the graph, it is smaller or equal $\mathbb{A}(G)$.

Comment: @dtldarek , I typed the question wrongly, I meant that $\mathbb{A} = \min _\pi \{\Delta_\pi\}$

Comment: I thought there has to be some typo ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take *any* subset $U \subseteq V$ and *any* permutation $\pi$. Define $v_k$ as the first vertex of $U$ in $\pi$, that is,

$$ k = \min \big\{i \in \mathbb{N} \mid v_i \in U\big\}. $$

Observe that
$$\Delta_\pi \geq \deg_{\{v_{k+1},\ldots\}}(v_k) \geq \deg_{G'}(v_k) 
\geq \min_{u\in U} \big\{ \deg_{G'} (u) \big\} = \gamma(U).$$

As that works for all $U$'s and all $\pi$'s, we have $\mathbb{B}(G) \leq \mathbb{A}(G)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Why does $\deg_{\{v_{k+1},...,v_n \}} (v_k) \geq \deg_{G^{'}} (v_k)$ ? isn't it the opposite?

Comment: $k$ is the minimal index of vertices of $U$, so all $G'$-neighbors of $v_k$ are in the set $\{v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n\}$.